# How do I access the files with git lsf attributes on them?

Tags: git

I came across some articles and SO threads about `git lsf` that should be used when dealing with large data files. That is great, however how do I pass the binary files initially? I can't get my head around

the `.gitattribute` file contains `Content/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text`

I did:

````
```
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin master
```
````

That took a while, it's 4GB of data in total, however when my friend cloned that repo, he only got 4MB of a repo size, how can he get the assets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however when my friend cloned that repo, he only got 4MB of a repo size, how can he get the assets?

That would be [`git lfs fetch`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-fetch.1.ronn)

> ### Examples:
>
> ```
> git config lfs.fetchinclude "textures,images/foo*"
> ```
>
> This will only fetch objects referenced in paths in the `textures` folder, and files called `foo*` in the `images` folder
>
> ```
> git config lfs.fetchinclude "*.jpg,*.png,*.tga"
> ```
>
> Only fetch JPG/PNG/TGA files, wherever they are in the repository.

`git lfs fetch --all` would get everything.

Comment: Thanks, that's wass exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: One thing, now it downloaded and `.git` folde rhas 4GB, how do i replace the pointer's to the actual files?

Comment: @user1767754 `git lfs pull` should update the files in the working directory.

Comment: @user1767754 If not, emove all the files handled by git LFS, found by cat `.gitattributes`, and run `git checkout .`